# *Android Configuration Qualifiers - how do they work?

Tags: android, resources, drawable, android-drawable, image-scaling

My tablet is a Google Nexus 10 and it has an XHDPI screen with a size (I believe) of Extra-Large.

- I've put the assets for it into my **drawable-xhdpi** folder.
- I then decided to test creating another folder, namely **drawable-xlarge-xhdpi** and stick some assets into it. I left the other resources in **drawable-xhdpi**.
- I ran the app and it ignored the resources in **drawable-xhdpi** and picked up the resources from **drawable-xlarge-xhdpi**.
- I then renamed **drawable-xlarge-xhdpi** to **drawable-large-xhdpi**.
- I ran the app and it ignored the resources in **drawable-xhdpi** and picked up the resources from **drawable-large-xhdpi**.
- I then renamed **drawable-large-xhdpi** to **drawable-normal-xhdpi**.
- I ran the app and it ignored the resources in **drawable-xhdpi** and picked up the resources from **drawable-normal-xhdpi**.
- I then renamed **drawable-normal-xhdpi** to **drawable-small-xhdpi**..
- I ran the app and this time, it ignored the resources in **drawable-small-xhdpi** and picked up the resources from **drawable-xhdpi**.

So it seems that the Android System appears to see the Nexus 10 as having a 'normal', 'large' and 'extra large' screen.

I have no idea what's going on here, but I'm sure there's someone out there who has some handle on this and who could

**Edit**

It just gets weirder, even if I put some resources into a folder called **drawable-normal-ldpi** (Could not be farther from my actual device which is XLarge (Screen) and XHDPI (density)), it *still* takes resources from that folder and ignores the ones in the XHDPI folder.

I read through, and thought I'd understood the [Official docs on this subject](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) but my latest test shows that I'm clearly not.